# SDL Key Pressing

Tags: c++, button, keyboard, key, sdl

I have this piece of code:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
  if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
    switch(event.key.keysym.sym) {
      case SLDK_UP:    dir=1; break;
      case SLDK_DOWN:  dir=2; break;
      case SLDK_RIGHT: dir=3; break;
      case SLDK_LEFT:  dir=4; break;
      default:                break;
    }
  }
  else if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    quit = true;
```

in order to manage key presses for a game i'm writing. (BTW I'm following lazy foo's 8th tut for that)

The thing is that the compiler complains about `SLDK_UP`, `SLDK_DOWN` and so on. It states that they are not declared in this scope. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a simple typo with `SLDK_*` which should be `SDLK_*`.